# My list doesn't want to convert properly in c++

Tags: c++, list

I have this function:

```
void move(float delta, std::list<Cube>& cubes)
```

And i call it like this:

```
player.move(delta, cubes);
```

It gives the Error

> error C2664: 'void Player::move(float,std::list &)': cannot convert
> argument 2 from 'std::list<Cube,std::allocator>' to 'std::list
> &'

I defind cubes like this:

```
std::list<Cube> cubes;
```

And then add a cube:

```
cubes.push_back(Cube(0.f, 600.f, 1280.f, 120.f, sf::Color(255, 255, 255, 255)));
```

simple code:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <list>


class Cube
{
public:
    float x, y, w, h;
    
    Cube(float x, float y, float w, float h)
    {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        this->w = w;
        this->h = h;
    }
};


void move(std::list<Cube>& cubes)
{
    
}


int main()
{
    std::list<Cube> cubes;
    cubes.push_back(Cube(0.f, 0.f, 100.f, 100.f));

    move(cubes);
}
```

What the problem? pls answer.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Also, when posting error messages, please format them as code.

Comment: Is there a mismatch between Player::move(..)'s declaration and definition? Also, please upload an easily executable code piece. It would be easier for us :)

Comment: i uploaded the "simple code"

Comment: The simple code is [working](https://godbolt.org/z/x1fq587oT). This is not a [mcve] as it doesn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: i dont know. in my code its the exact same, but its giving error.

Comment: What is the exact version of the compiler you are using, what are the compiler flags, and what are **all** the compiler messages you get when compiling **the simple program**?